# Awk: Why round up number doesn't work with range?

Tags: awk, floating-point, range, rounding

Trying understand why the following code will print my desired range from 0-30

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=300;k=sprintf("%.0f",n/10);x=k*1;for (i=0;i<=x;i++) print i}' /dev/null
```

While, the following code will only print number ranging from 0-3

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=300;k=sprintf("%.0f",n/10);for (i=0;i<=k;i++) print i}' /dev/null
```

Is there a better way to round up a number and print the range?

Comment: If your question is really about how to round up a number, it'd make sense in the example to use a number than needs rounding. `300/10` is `30` - no rounding involved.

Answer (score 1):

What are you hoping the sprintf() will do for you? All it really does is convert the number you want into a string so then the later comparison is string-based rather than numeric which is why you have a problem since the string `"4"` is larger than the string `"30"`. You do not need /dev/null at the end of the line btw. All you need is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=300;k=n/10;for (i=0;i<=k;i++) print i}'
```

Actually, I see you said something about rounding up a number, is that what you're hoping the sprintf will do? Most [s]printf implementations do unbiased rounding so it will round `.5` towards even rather than up or down as you might expect. Consider this instead to control the rounding direction:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=6.5; print x, int(x), sprintf("%.0f",x), int(x+0.5)}'
6.5 6 6 7

$ awk 'BEGIN{x=7.5; print x, int(x), sprintf("%.0f",x), int(x+0.5)}'
7.5 7 8 8
```

Note in the above that for positive numbers `int(x)` always rounds down and `int(x+0.5)` always rounds up while `sprintf("%0.f",x)` rounds towards the nearest even number. To do it for negative numbers too:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=1; print x, "down:", int(x<0 ? x-0.5 : x), "up:", int(x<0 ? x : x+0.5)}'
1 down: 1 up: 1
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=0.5; print x, "down:", int(x<0 ? x-0.5 : x), "up:", int(x<0 ? x : x+0.5)}'
0.5 down: 0 up: 1
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=0; print x, "down:", int(x<0 ? x-0.5 : x), "up:", int(x<0 ? x : x+0.5)}'
0 down: 0 up: 0
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=-0.5; print x, "down:", int(x<0 ? x-0.5 : x), "up:", int(x<0 ? x : x+0.5)}'
-0.5 down: -1 up: 0
$ awk 'BEGIN{x=-1; print x, "down:", int(x<0 ? x-0.5 : x), "up:", int(x<0 ? x : x+0.5)}'
-1 down: -1 up: -1
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function for more info but I don't understand why that function there is so complicated.

Comment: Imagine rounding the number `0.5-2**-54`, while rounding in the traditional way for positive numbers can be implemented as `int(x+0.5)`, it will round this number to 1 while it should be 0. I could not find any other numbers that satisfy this criterion.

Comment: Thanks for that. In my gawk version at least `0.49999999999999991` produces the correct output but `0.49999999999999992` rounds up to 1 instead of down to 0. Now I have to decide if I'd care enough to actually use round() just to handle that case given that number itself would probably be the product of floating point calculations which themselves involve some approximations. Hmm....

Comment: 0.49999999999999992 is numerically equivalent to 0.5 in standard IEEE binary64

Answer (score 0):

From the [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) documentation, it is quite clear that `sprintf` returns a string type which you need to convert to an integer during the loop

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=300;k=sprintf("%.0f",n/10);for (i=0;i<=k+0;i++) print i}' /dev/null
#                                                   ^^^^ adding +0 casts any string type to an 
#                                                       numeric type in awk
```

In the first example though, since you have the variable `x` which you multiply with 1 and use that in the for loop, the cast conversion had taken place.

Like Ed’s comment, you could just do this once instead on every for loop iteration

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=300;k=(sprintf("%.0f",n/10)+0); for (i=0;i<=k;i++) print i}' /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a better solution than creating another variable.